# Xenforo does not show updated values after manually changing in database

Tags: xenforo

I have a Xenforo forum with Waindigo Custom Fields addon. I created a custom group with 3 fields: Address, Latitude and Longitude.

A thread is created with initial values as example below:
- Address A
- Lat A
- Long A

Later on I want to change these values. Because Xenforo & Custom Fields addon don't provide the function to change them. I decided to make change directly on database. The table is MySql is xf_thread_field_value. I changed values of 3 rows coresponse to that thread.

But after refreshing the browser (CTRL+F5), the values are still the same. I tried to cron the cache in admin panel but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to rebuild posts cache. XF keeps the posts from last days cached for performance (the exact number of days is configurable in the Options)

To rebuild the caches, go to Tools -> Rebuild Caches